# Elegant way to execute code on function exit in Dart

Tags: dart

Suppose we need to execute some code when a function finishes, no matter how.
Example:

```
void myFunc() async {
    await myLock.acquire();
    if(...) {
        myLock.release();
        return;
    }
    ...
    myLock.release();
}
```

Many languages have features that allow to achieve this in a more elegant way than just manually calling `myLock.release()` before every `return` statement (For example `defer` in Go). Is something like that also possible in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart does not have RAII.  You instead would need to use [`try`-`finally`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#finally).

(Dart did recently (in 2.17) add [`Finalizer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Finalizer-class.html)s, but those would fire when objects are garbage collected, which might happen at some non-deterministic time, if ever.)

Answer (score 1):

And just for the record, an example of using `try`/`finally`:

```dart
void myFunc() async {
  await myLock.acquire();
  try {
    if(...) {
        return;
    }  
    ...
  } finally {
    myLock.release();
  }
 
}
```

You'd want to start the `try` *after* allocating the resource, so that you don't try to release if allocation throws.